# How do I make a function f(x) = y out of a 2d path?

Tags: javascript, function, math

I have a 2d path defined on a single variable:

```
var point = path(t);  // --> [0.113, 0.883]
```

Iterating over `t` from `0` to `1` I can enumerate the entire path and then graph the successive pairs `[x,y]`.  The path is not overlapping on the x-axis, so in theory I should be able to make a function out of it, though the exact approach is eluding me at the moment.  If I just project down to the x-axis and take [x,y] --> y, then the graph is wrong because we are moving through x and y, so if there is time spent moving through the y axis but not the x this will not be reflected when projected to one dimension.  How do I build the function that represents my 2d path as a mapping from x to y?

EDIT:  Here is an image of the curve (white line is the bezier spline path(t) --> [x,y], grey circles are the original data points and the green line is the original keyframe data I am using to generate the curve.  Ignore the rest of the lines):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question, you want to call path(t) for t in[0.000, 0.001,...0.999,1] that's right ?

Comment: No, I want to turn path(t) --> [x, y] into f(x) --> y.  So turn the [x,y] generating function into one where I provide x and get the corresponding y back.

Comment: Where does the path(t) function come from? If you wrote it, can you re-arrange the equations to eliminate t?

Comment: I have defined path(t) already as a 2d bezier curve spline.  In principle it should not matter where it came from as long as it is a function of the form path(t) --> [x,y].

Comment: You need to study your path, is it a linear is it monotone, you probably need to use integral function to see the different variations and when it crosses x and y axes etc etc ... http://dl.uncw.edu/digilib/mathematics/algebra/mat111hb/functions/graphs/graphs.html

Comment: As we talk about bezier curves, how would should this function handle the case where there are more then one point for a x value?

Comment: So the way it was constructed it is guaranteed to not have more that one point for an x value... That is what lead me to believe I could cast it as a function f(x) = y.

Comment: Also, it is restricted to the interval [0, 1] for both x and y, so there are no negative values or axis crossing.

Comment: it depends how precise is your t variation you can for example use t for 0, 0.5 and 1 and this could be very easy to implement ...

Comment: So basically you would need to store each result of path(t), then request this result with an x value for getting the corresponding y ?

Comment: So are you saying I need to numerically integrate?  I was hoping to construct an actual continuous function f(x) = y, since the original path(t) is continuous.

Comment: You could just fit your data to a polynomial of the form y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d (you might not need the ax^3 term). Some research should give you a method.

Comment: So, if it is single valued for any x, then why not use interp1, or spline, then ppval?

Comment: Isn't there some way to solve for x?  I would rather not use another approximation of my approximation!

Comment: If there were a way to solve for x without using approximation, I'm pretty sure graphics experts would have found it by now. It's kind of important to them.

Comment: Ha!  Alright then, I did not realize this was such a fundamental problem.  So... best ways to approximate it?  My polynomial has a lot of spurious elements around complex control points...

Comment: AFAIK, a polynomial fit to a Bezier spline has a good chance of being an exact fit given that the spline is single-valued for all x in the range which you are considering. Could you post a picture of a typical curve in your original question?

Comment: Do you actually have (and can disclose) the source for for `path(t) -> [x, y]` ?

Comment: @Andrew Morton:  I added an image.  Alnitak:  It is a simple bezier spline in 2 dimensions, I can provide the source if you wish but in principle it should not make a difference.

Comment: Ah, looking at the image I'd say just use linear interpolation between data points rather than trying for a simple y=f(x). Or do you need to use f'(x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out!  I made a binary search algorithm that tries path(x) and determines the difference between the x returned in the [x,y] pair and the x that is sought.  Then it adds half the difference and tries again.  Given an epsilon, this approaches the right [x,y] pair in logarithmic time!

I have code if anyone wants it.

EDIT:  Here's the code (for the binary search part):

```
function buildBinary(at, epsilon) {
  return function(x) {
    var guess = x;
    var near = at(guess);
    var approx = near[0];
    var diff = x - approx;

    while (Math.abs(diff) > epsilon) {
      guess = guess + diff * 0.5;
      near = at(guess);
      approx = near[0];
      diff = x - approx;
    }

    return near[1];
  }
}
```

`at` is the function path(t) -> [x,y] and `epsilon` is how close is acceptable.  Works great!

Comment: Please post it either here or somewhere.

Comment: This is not using binary search... you are mixing up the index domain (the argument to `at`) with the `x` domain. To do a binary search start with `index0=0`, `index1=1`, shoot at the average `(index0+index1)/2` and then decide which of the two vars you should update using the average.

Comment: Sure, so it is "binary search-like", inspired by binary search, not a by the book implementation.  I feel like my approach is more efficient (converges in fewer steps) because it starts with a good guess and refines it, rather than starting with the entire range and spending a couple cycles to encounter the general area of the solution.  I would have to run an experiment to find out, but in the meantime this is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your function doesn't overlap isn't so important but perhaps you can map it to a spatial index or a space filling curve? A morton curve reduce the dimension and is self-avoiding and non-overlapping curve. The shape is like a z curve and it's a fractal dimension and it means it's an approximation? It's often use in map application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx and here: http://www.drdobbs.com/database/space-filling-curves-in-geospatial-appli/184410998.

Comment: That sounds interesting.  Do you have a good reference to spatial indexing or morton curves?  (I will look around as well.)

Comment: Hmm... not exactly what I'm looking for, though very interesting!  Thanks.